# Can't SaveChanges with Entity Framework in ASP.Net MVC 5 in create action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

When executing the post create action, It goes throw the if statement but the context.saveChanges(); doesn't work. And go to the catch

Here is the Task class:

```
public partial class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string TName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Creation On")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TCreationOn { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Due Date")]
    public System.DateTime TDueDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Updated Date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TLastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Purpose")]
    public string TPurpose { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string TDescription { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Comment")]
    public string TComment { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public Nullable<int> TCreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Taken By")]
    public Nullable<int> TTakenBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public Nullable<int> TStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
}
```

And The two create action:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SelectList users = new SelectList(context.Users.ToList<User>(), "UserID", "UserName");
        SelectList status = new SelectList(context.Status.ToList<Status>(), "StatusID", "StatusName");
        ViewBag.TCreatedBy = users;
        ViewBag.TTakenBy = users;
        ViewBag.TStatus = status;

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Task/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Tasks.Add(task);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            SelectList users = new SelectList(context.Users.ToList<User>(), "UserID", "UserName");
            SelectList status = new SelectList(context.Status.ToList<Status>(), "StatusID", "StatusName");
            ViewBag.TCreatedBy = users;
            ViewBag.TTakenBy = users;
            ViewBag.TStatus = status;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

What is the problem in this code?

Comment: And which exception is thrown?

Comment: IT go to the same create view with no exception

Comment: "but the context.saveChanges(); doesn't work. And go to the catch". If it enters the catch then there's an exception, you have trapped it, but there's an exception.

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: And what contains the `EntityValidationErrors` property of the exception? It should be a list of errors.

Comment: Dude, please, be a bit proactive, open that class and check it's content, it must give you a message with the exact error.

Comment: "The TID field is required"
But I am in the database make a default value for it and it is auto generated key in specific format

Comment: How is it autogenerated? through a trigger? an stored procedure?

Comment: yes, throw a trigger 

create trigger insertTask
on Task
after insert as
begin
    update Task
    set TID = 'QA' + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '')
                   + RIGHT( '000' + CAST(inserted.ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
    from Task
    join inserted on inserted.ID = Task.ID;
end;
go

Comment: Then you have set-up it wrong, let me explain, you have set the field to be non-null, so you can't insert a null value, the trigger is executed AFTER the insert, so nothing is replaced as there's no possibility to insert the data because TID is null. You have two options, set TID to "" and then the trigger will change it or change the field to accept null values and that will solve everything (i would opt for the second option, it's safer if you have an unique index on that column).

Comment: The TID column is the primary key so it will not allow null

Comment: I doubt it, ID is the primary key, TID is an string field.

Comment: I used the Identity column (ID) to generate a string primary key (TID)

Comment: Replacing the primary key AFTER insert is an extremely bad idea. Use as primary key the ID column and let the TID field to be a unique indexed field, it will work for any query as if it were the primary key and you will be able to insert temporarily the null value.

Comment: It works thank you for your help and your time

Comment: Glad it works...